# How to persist an in RAM value between Android app launches?

Tags: memory, android

Is there a way in Android to persist a value in the RAM, so it is available to the application while device is powered on?

So the app would store a value there first time it is started, and then until device is rebooted, the value can be read by the app even if app is closed/restarted, put to background/resumed? This value cannot be saved into flash memory.

p.s. It is ok to lose that data if app is force stopped via Settings.

Comment: It's called SharedPreferences!

Comment: No it's not. See below.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. You should instead use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: SharedPreferences do not meet the requirements listed: 1) They do not store values in RAM, but in file on flash memory 2) they persist data not only between app launches but also between reboots.

One of the options I tried - storing the value in sticky Service. But still, cannot reliably keep it running without restarts (i.e. loss of data).

Answer (score 0):

You can save your data to a bundle in `onSaveInstanceState()` and restore it in `onCreate()`. Just make sure you don't terminate the app when Back is pressed - leave it stopped instead

Comment: onSaveInstanceState() belongs to Activity's lifecycle, not Application. And I have a lot of activities, not sure how to synchronize them all. Also, app can be killed in low memory conditions. Will savedInstanceState be kept in this case?

Comment: Yes, instance state will be saved when your app is killed by the system and not saved when you exit it normally. You may want to check http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: Thanks, msh. I'm pretty up to speed on this concept, and this is exactly why I'm posting the question here - it doesn't work for what I'm trying to achieve. And I wasn't able to find any standard mechanism that does. However, a hack involving running a service in background and caching data there, plus saving it in instance state as well seems to work. If no one suggests something better, I'll post that solution here.